# Button insert link on front wp_editor not working

Tags: javascript, links, front-end, wp-editor

I display a wp_editor on the front-end and everything was going fine until a recent WP update.

Now, the "insert/edit link" is not working due to a Javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'tempHide' of undefined
```

This error only appears on front-end. The back-end is going fine.

I've looked for it on StackExchange and Google. Maybe I'm not using the right keywords, but I don't find anyone with the same problem...

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it at last!

Using the browser debugger, I found that there was a "editor.wp" which was undefined (in the complete version of the js file).
Then I understood that the "wordpress" plugin was not used in the editor.

When calling the function wp_editor, I was setting a list of plugin : paste, wplink, textcolor.
It was working until a specific WordPress update.

I just had to add the "wordpress" plugin in the list, and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a theme error. Try a different theme (like the standard ones - Twenty-whatevers).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but the wp_editor is inserted in the theme :) Do you think it could be a compatibility problem with some other JS?

Comment: Problems are usually themes or plugins. WP 4.8 caused some issues with themes.  But you could quickly disable all plugins (remember which ones were active, although you shouldn't really have any inactive plugins) and then re-enable plugins one at a time to find the culprit. You could (with appropriate knowledge) look for the 'tempHide' in plugin/theme code.

Comment: Thank you! I already looked for it... but with no success (the only things calling tempHide is tinyMCE itself).
This is quite strange because the only thing that changed is the WordPress update ! :) And the last update doesn't correct it.

Comment: Is it possible that your theme or a plugin is loading an older copy of TinyMCE or some other JS add-in? The googles show some indication of this error in older TinyMCE versions. Perhaps disabling all plugins then testing? Can you look at the generated page source code to find where in the template the error occurs (perhaps by searching for some 'class' code that is near the generated error? Or looking at the error.log for help (perhaps turning on wp_debug temporarily)?